# Factory returning a new function calling a target function with some default parameters

Tags: typescript

How can I:

- Create a factory function where default parameters may be provided
- The generated function should require (required) parameters not given as default, but accept all parameters

This is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
interface Alpha {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

export function alpha(params: Alpha) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
}

export function alphaDefaults(defaults: Partial<Alpha>) {
  // Not sure what Defaults should be...
  const func = (params: Defaults) => alpha({ ...defaults, ...params });
  return func;
}

const fn2 = alphaDefaults({});

// should complain about missing a and b
fn2({});

const fn3 = alphaDefaults({ a: "A" });

// should complain about missing b
fn3({ a: "NotA" });
fn3({});

const fn4 = alphaDefaults({ b: "B" });
// should complain about missing a
fn4({ b: "NotB" });
fn4({});

const fn5 = alphaDefaults({ a: "A", b: "B" });
// should not complain
fn5({ a: "NotA" });
fn5({ b: "NotB" });
fn4({ a: "Hi", b: "There" });
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1pDXW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes that also works. Just as the answer from kelly . It's interesting to compare similarities and differences in your approaches. Hm. Hard to say which one is "better". Really cool to see both. Will think a little about which one to accept, but I definitely appreciate both of them! Thank you!

Comment: I usually write up fairly <strike>longwinded</strike> uh, *comprehensive* answers, so I won't bother unless you give me some indication that you'd accept it.  And since kelly's approach is similar anyway (the real difference is just that I'm only making it generic in the key type and they are making it generic in the object type) I'll just leave it alone.

Comment: @jcalz Okey. I'm not good enough with Typescript yet to have a feeling for one way or the other. Regardless of posted answer or not I think your comment is really valuable. I'll just accept Kelly then but I am grateful for you taking the time too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a generic to infer and "store" what was given to the initial call, we can create the correct type based on that.

Pick all keys from `Alpha` that weren't given in `Given`, then intersect that with `Partial<Alpha>` to get the rest of the keys that are optional.

```
function alphaDefaults<Given extends Partial<Alpha>>(defaults: Given) {
  const func = (params: Pick<Alpha, Exclude<keyof Alpha, keyof Given>> & Partial<Alpha>) => alpha({ ...defaults, ...params } as Alpha);
  return func;
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLyVVW)